# I want to pass a selected value in a combobox to a parameter in powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have a combo box on a Windows form created using XAML. I need to pass a selected combo box value to a parameter in my script. I want the code to only run when I make the selection (e.g. like a button click event, if this is possible).

I have tried using different method types after `$cboUseCase.` at the start of the code. Right now this code is trying to run when the Window is loading, I need it to run only when a selection is made. Thank you for your help.

```
$cboUseCase.({$configSelect = ($cboUseCase.SelectedItem.toString())
&$global:UCM.setConfigSelection -selection $configSelect})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I really understand your question. Here is a  runnable example showing how to "trap" a selection change in a combo box.

Maybe it can give you a track to follow:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('PresentationFramework') | Out-Null

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen"
    SizeToContent = "WidthAndHeight" ShowInTaskbar = "True" Background = "lightgray"> 
    <StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$ComboBox1 = $Window.FindName("ComboBox1")

$ComboBox1.add_SelectionChanged( { 

    param($sender, $args)

    $selected = $sender.SelectedItem.Content
    Write-Host "Selected: $selected"
} )


$Window.Showdialog() | Out-Null
```